# How can I pass a function object to a function that expects a void * pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a function that expects to be passed a normal reference to a function

void func( * pOtherFunc );

I would like to create multiple functions with slight changes and pass those in- I was thinking of function objects.  How do I pass this function the functionobject?

Comment: The problem isn't _passing_, but resolving back what actually was passed!

Comment: Compiler just says "I can't execute that."

Comment: Sounds like I have to explicitly create all the functions I want to pass to this other function...I am sad.

Comment: If you could show what the signature of `pOtherFunc` is, and what exactly one of these function objects you want to pass to `func` looks like, someone might be able to give you a more definitive answer

Comment: @MKaras what compiler says "I can't execute that"?

Comment: Obviously `void func( * pOtherFunc );` won't compile anywhere, so presumably you have something different. Also your question says the function expects a "normal reference to a function", but the title says it expects a "`void *` pointer", they can't both be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
void func(* pOtherFunc );
```

You cannot pass this a function object. You can pass it a pointer to function.

```
void func(int(*pf)(int)) { cout << pf(3); }
int f(int x) { return x; }
int g(int x) { return x*x; }

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
    int (*p1)(int) = (int(*)(int))f;
    int (*p2)(int) = (int(*)(int))g;
    func(p1);
    func(p2);
    return 0;
}
```

To pass around function objects requires a different signature.

Answer (score 2):

**Traditional function pointer:**

I think your pointer to a function was not well defined.  Here a sample:

```
void test (int a)   // first function to be called 
{   cout <<"TEST function: "<<a;  }

void test2 (int a)   // other function to be called
{   cout <<"second test function: "<<a; }

void func( void (*pOtherFunc)(int a) )  // your function 
{
    cout << "Call:  "; 
    (*pOtherFunc)(10);
    cout<<endl; 
}

int main(int ac, char**av) 
{
    func (test); 
    func (test2); 
        return 0;
}
```

If you want to have a variable which point to your fonction, you could write something like:

```
void (*pf)(int a); 
pf = test; 
func(pf);
```

As you see, your function pointers should always have the same signature; otherwhise the compiler would not know how to pass them the parameters.

**Alternative with function objects**

Another alternative, especially if you have functions with additional parameters, could be to use objects.  For this you'll need a base object, and all other "function objects" shoudld be derived from the base object.

```
class myFunction {
public:
    virtual void myfunc(int a) {  cout <<"class function: "<<a<<endl; }
};

class mynewFunction : myFunction {
public: 
    virtual void myfunc(int a) {  cout <<"other class function: "<<a<<endl; }
};
```

You can then use these classes to instantiate objects or pointer to objects:

```
int main(int ac, char**av) 
{
    myFunction f; 
    mynewFunction g; 

    f.myfunc(10); 
    g.myfunc(10); 
}
```

And of course, you can pass these objects as parameters to other functions.